# Issues with PHP mail() function

Tags: email, php

I'm having issues with a basic contact PHP script I'm using to send form data.
The [page](http://www.edenapartments.co.uk/bookings.html) in question.

My PHP is pretty limited, but I can't spot anything obvious with my syntax that could be the problem.

The script does some basic error check and stores the results in a variable $error

```
if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
{
    $error .= 'Invalid E-mail !!!';
}
```

and then the PHP in question:

```
if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
    "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n"
    ."Subject: BOOKING FORM SUBMISSION \r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion());
if($mail)
  {
    echo 'OK';
  }
  else {
    echo 'Mail called, no mail';
  }
}
else
  {
    echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
  }
}
```

If I input bob@hj as an email, the PHP script recognises this error and I get a response back from the script: "Invalid email" so I can confirm the form data is being sent to the script looking at the page in the inspector shows the data is being parsed correctly.

And when there are no errors, the response is "Mail called, no mail sent" so I presume there is something wrong with the mail() function I'm calling.

I've tried simplifying the header as just a straight from field with the same results.

Any Ideas?
Thanks ahead to the great community here on stack.

Thought it might be worth including the jquery I use to call the script, but given the PHP's response "Mail called, no mail" I presume it's not the jQuery causing the problem..

```
jQuery("#booking-form").submit(function(){
            _CONTACT = jQuery(this);
            var str = _CONTACT.serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "basic_booking_form/booking.php",
                   data: str,
                   success: function(msg){
                        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                            if(msg == 'OK') {
                                result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent Succesfully. Thank you.</div>';
                                jQuery("#fields").hide();
                                _CONTACT.hide();
                                _CONTACT.html(result).slideDown("slow");
                                _CONTACT.html(result);
                            }
                            else {
                                result = msg;
                                _CONTACT.find('#note').html(result).slideDown("slow");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });
```

Comment: There is not enought information. Can you show us all errors on page with `display_errors = 1` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: Enable error reporting and request the page (without ajax). Report any errors you find. Also, your script is WIDE open to abuse. Without sanitizing the `$name` and `$email` inputs, you are allowing anyone to inject arbitrary headers into this email.

Comment: Off Topic: You should use `filter_var` to check if the email is valid. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: I Apologise, I've yet to gain any understanding of error checking in PHP.

I've disabled the ajax call and the forms action is set to the PHP script. I believe I have set the error checking variables using the following statement at the top of the PHP file:

    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set("track_errors", 1);
    ini_set("html_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Will this suffice to see any errors yourselves?

Comment: On the abuse side, in researching this issue, yes I had come to discover the delicate nature of this method and have started reseaching "PHPmailer" as a potential solution.
The form is however a sort of temporary measure until we can introduce a payment gateway..so I assume this would suffice until then? Or do you really recommend I try and get PHP mailer working?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

---

UPDATE
Thanks to everyone who was about to pitch in and help on this, I'm pleased to say I've got a much better solution working using "SwiftMail". For those of you dabbling with these common PHP contact form tutorials, I highly recommend using it. 
Implementing it was simple and now I'm sending mail using my own mail servers smtp settings rather than PHPs mail() function.

The resultant PHP code (after including swiftmail in my file structure):

```
<?php

require_once '../swift_mail/lib/swift_required.php';

include 'config.php';
  error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
  $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
  include 'functions.php';
  $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
  $apartment = trim($_POST['apartment']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $tel = trim($_POST['tel']);
  $mob = trim($_POST['mob']);
  $arrive = trim($_POST['arrive']);
  $depart = trim($_POST['depart']);
  $guests = trim($_POST['guests']);
  $guests13 = trim($_POST['guests13']);
  $accept = trim($_POST['accept']);

  $message = "Name: ".$name."\n"."Tel: ".$tel."\n"."Mobile: ".$mob."\n"."Apartment: ".$apartment."\n"."Arrive: ".$arrive."\n"."Depart: ".$depart."\n"."Guests: ".$guests."\n"."Guests under 13: ".$guests13."\n".stripslashes($_POST['message'])."\n"."Terms Accepted: ".$accept;

  $error = '';

  // Create the Transport
  $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.******.co.uk', 26)
  ->setUsername('******')
  ->setPassword('******');
  if(!$transport) {
    $error .= 'error creating transport';
  }

  // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  // Check name
  if(!$name)
  {
    $error .= 'You need to enter a name';
  }
  // Check email
  if(!$email)
  {
    $error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail. It will not be stored or added to any mailing list.';
  }
  if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
  {
    $error .= 'Invalid E-mail !!!';
  }
  if(!$accept)
  {
    $error .= 'You must accept the terms and conditions to make a reservation.';
  }
  if(!$error)
  {
    $mail_to_send = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    // Give the message a subject
    ->setSubject('Booking Form Submission')
    // Set the From address with an associative array
    ->setFrom(array($email => $name))
    ->setReplyTo($email)
    // Set the To addresses with an associative array
    ->setTo(WEBMASTER_EMAIL)
    // Give it a body
    ->setBody($message);

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($mail_to_send);
    if($result) {
      echo 'OK';
    } 
    else {
      echo 'mailer not successful';
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<pre>
    <div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>
    </pre>';
  }
}
?>
```